# Why does the delete event occur on file write?

Tags: c++, c, macos

I am using Kernel Queues in OS X to watch for file events ([sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005289-CH5-SW2)) and when I run the sample code on a file **`foo.bar`** and then modify the file, the sample prints out that it recieved a delete event for the file. How could this be? Is this a bug?

Comment: How did you modify the file, with an editor? (editors tend to rename the file and create it again, or perform other tricks to maintain reliability)

Comment: @wildplasser I was using TextEdit on OS X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "modifying" the file, I take it you mean editing it or whatever.

No, this is not a bug. Most text editors write the contents of a modified file in another file, then flush and close it, then delete the original and rename the other file to the original.

On the other hand, some "simple" edit operations, such as appending a line to a file using `echo whatever >>thefile`, will not delete the file but open/seek/write/flush/close it.

Comment: wow, that is ridiculuous. I would never have expected an editor to delete the file and then resave it. thanks!

Comment: Well, if it weren't doing so, just imagine the work it would have to do to insert _one_ character at some random point in the file ;)

Comment: That is the only safe way to modify a file. Otherwise, if the system crashes or the program is terminated during the modification, the file can be left in a corrupt state.

Comment: @fge an fopen(path, "wb") wouldnt delete the file, would it?

Comment: @chacham15 I don't know that "b" flag to fopen(), but no it wouldn't. Deleting a file is a call to `unlink()`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz interestingly enough, TextEdit, at least, only deletes it on the first edit, all subsequent edits are normal writes.

Comment: @fge the "b" flag is for binary reading/writing. You'll get weird EOF errors on windows if you dont use it. Also, fopen is a library call. It itself could call unlink.

Comment: @chacham15 are you sure about that? You say you are tracing modifications to a file -- but a file is an inode. Once it is deleted, I am not sure your tracing is valid anymore. What do the Apple docs say about that?

Comment: @fge you could be right, on a delete i might need to get a new file descriptor for the file (currently I am using the same one (well, the sample code, that is))

Comment: @chacham15 definitely so, yes... And I am pretty confident that fopen() never calls unlink()  ;)

Comment: The whole inotify-stuff is based on inodes, not files. Names are only looked up in the directory at the beginning of the operation, after that the inode is monitored. (IIRC there is an option to 'follow' a file, or 'rescan' a directory, not sure)

Comment: @chacham15 writing to a file with standard c calls will not cause the delete-and-replace behavior; it's things like NSData's [writeToFile:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIAEAHFJ) that do this.